# Developing Linux-compatible Command Line Utility under Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, c, linux

which is the best way to develop a linux-compatible Command Line Utility under Mac OS X Lion? It should parse a really big XML file (up to 300 GB) - probably with libxml - and convert it to somewhat JSON.

With XCode 4 there is the possiblity to develop Command Line Utilities (former Foundation Tools I think). Are these compatible to run on Linux Servers? It would be nice, cause I'm used to Objective-C a little bit.

Another approach would be native C. But I'm really no expert in programming C. Alternatives are maybe Perl or Ruby. PHP as CLI script isn't as fast as needed I think.

Any suggestions which is the easiest and at the same time fastest in context of parsing the XML data way?

Thanks in advance
Marco

Comment: Compiled binaries from mac os are not compatible with Linux. You need a recompilation on the Linux. So, you must develop utility using only Posix calls and libraries, available for linux. There is an objc compiler (gcc) on linux, but it is preinstalled on small number of machines.

Comment: There is also GNUStep, a non-Apple implementation of the OpenStep standard that forms the basis of Cocoa.

Comment: Java? Also, a 300 GB XML file probably means somebody somewhere has done something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With speed being a concern with files of that size, I'd be leaning toward C using libxml2 (available on both platforms) and use the progressive (event driven) interface.   Other then that, if you stick to posix I/O, you should be fine.

Mac OS also includes a Python implementation.   Python's readily available on Linux and has good libraries for both JSON and XML.